# Symmetric pages with typearea and amsart

Tags: header-footer, geometry, amsart, typearea

There is a `oneside` option in the package `typearea`. It is well suited for online documents, since the page layout is the same for every page. However, when used with  `amsart` document class, there is no switch of headers on even/odd pages. In two-sided mode there is title on odd pages and author name on even pages. Is it possible to make pages symmetric but with switching headers?

Solutions with `geometry` are also welcome.

Comment: just use twoside class option then use geometry and specify the same left and right margin

Comment: If you really want to use package `typearea`, try  option `twoside=semi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `amsart` class has its own method for setting the pagination parameters. In one- or twosided mode, the layout is symmetric.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{amsart}

\usepackage[auto-lang=false]{lipsum} % for mock text

\setlength{\textwidth}{17cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{25cm}
\calclayout

\begin{document}

\title{Title of the paper}
\author{Me}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-12]

\section{Another}

\lipsum[13-24]

\end{document}
```

[image]